# Как создать оповещение в стратегии на pine-script в Tradingview?

Tags: alert, tradingview

Как создать оповещение в стратегии на pine-script ? Есть стратегия, которая стрелками показывает точки входа, необходимо, чтобы была возможность создавать оповещения, и это встраивается в код с помощью функции alertcondition (если я правильно понял). Сам код:

```
//@version=3
    strategy("Strategy", shorttitle="Strategy", overlay=false,     initial_capital=1000, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=5, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.2, pyramiding=0)
    
    //Period
    startY = input(title="Start Year", defval = 2011, type=integer)
    startM = input(title="Start Month", defval = 1, type=integer,  minval = 1, maxval = 12)
    startD = input(title="Start Day", defval = 1, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
    finishY = input(title="Finish Year", defval = 2050, type=integer)
    finishM = input(title="Finish Month", defval = 12, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
    finishD = input(title="Finish Day", defval = 31, type=integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
    //finish = input(2019, 02, 28, 00, 00)
    timestart = timestamp(startY, startM, startD, 00, 00)
    timefinish = timestamp(finishY, finishM, finishD, 23, 59)
    window = time >= timestart and time <= timefinish ? true : false // Lenghth strategy
    
    length1 = input(21, minval=1), smoothK1 = input(3, minval=1), smoothD1 = input(3, minval=1)
    //length2 = input(5, minval=1), smoothK2 = input(1, minval=1), smoothD2 = input(1, minval=1)
    inh0 = input(title="Bottom Line", defval = 14, minval=0), inh1 = input(title="Upper Line", defval = 86, minval=0)
    
    k1 = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length1), smoothK1)
    d1 = sma(k1, smoothD1)
    plot(k1, color=blue)
    plot(d1, color=red)
    //k2 = sma(stoch(close, high, low, length2), smoothK2)
    //d2 = sma(k2, smoothD2)
    //plot(k2, color=orange)
    
    h1 = hline(inh1)
    h0 = hline(inh0)
    fill(h0, h1, color = aqua, transp=90)
    
    //open
    strategy.entry("LongEntryID", strategy.long, comment="LONG", when = crossover(k1, d1) and crossover(k1, inh0) and window)
    strategy.entry("ShortEntryID", strategy.short, comment="SHORT", when = crossunder(k1, d1) and crossunder(k1, inh1) and window)
    
    if crossunder(k1, d1) and crossunder(k1, inh1) and strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.close_all()
    if crossover(k1, d1) and crossover(k1, inh0) and strategy.position_size < 0
        strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте alert()

if ваше условие
alert("что то")